# Finding a <div> block with an 'id' and 'class' using Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

How can I search for the following block using Nokogiri:

```
<div id="live_list_cat_16" class="football-block sport-block" style="display:block;">
</div>
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#some_id` as the CSS selector.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="foo" class="bar">text</div>
    <div id="foo2" class="bar">more_text</div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('#foo').to_html # => "<div id=\"foo\" class=\"bar\">text</div>"
doc.search('div.bar').to_html # => "<div id=\"foo\" class=\"bar\">text</div><div id=\"foo2\" class=\"bar\">more_text</div>"
```

Remember, a particular ID is only allowed to exist once in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
doc.search('div#foo.bar')
```

How does this work?

- `search` and `at` method both accept CSS queries
- `div#foo` finds a div with id `foo`
- `div.bar` finds a div with class `bar`

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work. For some reason, when I search the page, it does not seem to be seeing anything passed a certain 'depth' of internal blocks. [Here is a snip of the HTML](http://imgur.com/v3rCq73). If i search for any class above and up to `.in-play-odds`, it returns it. However, it cannot find any sublcasses to `.in-play-odds` and if I search for `.in-play-odds`, it just returns an empty block as `<div id="live_list_container" class="in-play-odds">
</div>`. Any ideas why it cannot search within this block?

Comment: Maybe these `div` elements are created dynamically with javascript after the page loads. Did you check that they are present in the html string to you give to nokogiri?

Comment: I think you may be right about them being added dynamically. If that is the case, is there no way to scrape them using Nokogiri?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. There is probably an API call that gets the data as JSON or HTML, check with the network tab in the dev tools …